# Python `import A.B` does not work but `from A import B` works

Tags: python, python-import

This happened when I was using `sklearn` -

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.preprocessing.normalize # <-- would throw error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: module 'sklearn' has no attribute 'preprocessing'

>>> from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize # <-- works totally fine
```

I wonder how these two types of `import` are different? Thanks in advance!

Comment: What `import` did you do before the first line?

Comment: A module is not always an attribute of the package that contains it. The identical syntax used for attribute access and module paths doesn't help.

Comment: you did `import sklearn` -- but you wanted to do `import sklearn.processing` to make the `processing` sub-module of `sklearn` available

Comment: Let me guess, you only did `import sklearn` before the first line, which does not automatically import subpackages. If you did `import sklearn.preprocessing` (adding `.normalize` if that's a module name too), it would work just fine. Some packages eagerly import their subpackages (e.g. `os` eagerly pulls in `os.path` with it), but most don't if the subpackage isn't needed for the main package functionality, because it saves startup time to only import what is needed.

Comment: @ShadowRanger Thanks so much! This explains all my questions so clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have tried to do

```
>>> import sklearn
>>> sklearn.preprocessing.normalize
```

which would cause the error you show.

The problem is that you cannot access a submodule in this way. You have to do it this wan instead:

```
>>> import sklearn.preprocessing
>>> sklearn.preprocessing.normalize()
```

This imports the module that contains the `normalize()` function.

Alternatively you can import just the `normalize()` function:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize

normalize()
```

Answer (score 0):

In Python, you are importing libraries, including classes, methods and attributes. You are not importing methods. You must use `from` syntax to import any attributes or methods from a specific library.
So, `from sklearn.preprocessing import normalize` works because you are trying to import a **method** whose name is `normalize` from the library `sklearn.preprocessing`. But in `import sklearn.preprocessing.normalize` (which you forgot to write `import` in your syntax anyway!), Python assumes that you are trying to import a subclass that belongs to another library. So, Python will search to find that subclass with the name `normalize`, and it cannot find any. It will raise an error, as you see.